# Error when submit form with rvest (Error in enc2utf8(url))

Tags: r, web-scraping, rvest

I am trying to **scrape** data in "https://www.vndirect.com.vn/portal/thong-ke-thi-truong-chung-khoan/ket-qua-giao-dich.shtml". I am submitting a form using the rvest package in R and keep getting this error:

```
url <- "https://www.vndirect.com.vn/portal/thong-ke-thi-truong-chung-khoan/ket-qua-giao-dich.shtml" 

page_session <- html_session(url)                 
pgform <- html_form(page_session) %>% .[[1]]

filled_form <- set_values(form = pgform,
                          searchMarketStatisticsView.market = "HOSE",
                          strTradingDate = "06/08/2020")
```

Result from console:

```
Submitting with 'NULL'
Error in enc2utf8(url) : argument is not a character vector
```

When i do the same with "https://www.vndirect.com.vn/portal/thong-ke-thi-truong-chung-khoan/lich-su-gia.shtml", it's not error.
What am I doing wrong? Thank all.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I tried to find out why your code doesn't work but failed. Here is the solution that works:

```
library(rvest)
url <- "https://www.vndirect.com.vn/portal/thong-ke-thi-truong-chung-khoan/ket-qua-giao-dich.shtml" 

page_session <- html_session(url)                 

page_session <- rvest:::request_POST(page_session, 
                                     "https://www.vndirect.com.vn/portal/thong-ke-thi-truong-chung-khoan/ket-qua-giao-dich.shtml",
                                     body = list(model.downloadType = "",
                                                 pagingInfo.indexPage = "1", #change to page number
                                                 searchMarketStatisticsView.market = "HOSE",
                                                 strTradingDate = "03/06/2020"))
```

Comment: Thank @xwhitelight, your solution fix my error. Can you explain for me "rvest:::request_POST" mean? I don't find out request_POST function in rvest package

Comment: @Kevin_Nguyen Yeah, I knew about it by seeing other people using it on StackOverflow. It uses `httr::POST()` function under the hood to mimic the POST request we sent to the server.